# Area2D Node doesn't get Mouse Input

Tags: mouseevent, game-engine, game-development, godot, gdscript

So, I have an area 2D that gets input and creates a line using it that works in it's scene:

```
extends Area2D

signal vector_created(vector)

export var maximum_length := 200

var touch_down := false
var position_start := Vector2.ZERO
var position_end := Vector2.ZERO

var vector := Vector2.ZERO

func _ready() -> void:
    
    connect("input_event", self, "_on_input_event")


func _draw() -> void:
    draw_line(position_start - global_position, 
        position_end - global_position, 
        Color.blue, 
        8)
    
    draw_line(position_start - global_position, 
        position_start - global_position + vector, 
        Color.red, 
        16)


func _reset() -> void:
    position_start = Vector2.ZERO
    position_end = Vector2.ZERO
    vector = Vector2.ZERO
    
    update()
    

func _input(event) -> void:
    
    if event.is_action_released("ui_touch"):
        touch_down = false
        emit_signal("vector_created", vector)
        _reset()
    
    if not touch_down:
        return
    
    if event is InputEventMouseMotion:
        position_end = event.position
        vector = -(position_end - position_start).clamped(maximum_length)
    
        update()


func _on_input_event(_viewport, event, _shape_idx) -> void:
    
    if event.is_action_pressed("ui_touch"):
        touch_down = true
        position_start = event.position
```

But when I put it in the main scene it doesn't work. Why ?

[image]

I tried to change a an TextureRect, which was set to passing but still it doesn't work, I haven't figured it out since like a week!

Answer (score 0):

The issue I see is that you are mixing coordinate systems. The mouse position is in global space, but the points of the line are in local space. Which is fine is everything is at the origin and there is no scaling or rotation… But presumably that isn't the case.

For your `Line2D` it would be like this:

```
    $Line2D.set_point_position(0,$Line2D.to_local(first_touch))
    $Line2D.set_point_position(1,$Line2D.to_local(release))
```

And for `draw_line` it would be like this:

```
draw_line(to_local(first_touch),to_local(release),Color.blue,5)
```

Comment: Sorry but it was the wrong code, here is the good one, THX!